# How to scan the whole table contains the millions of records to return last month or last year records in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am the beginner in rails and facing following performance issues, guidance will be appreciated:
Wanted to show daily & monthly user registrations on flot graph for the specific outlet. How can I print this on dashboard ? =>

To get the users who are registered in the last month (for daily) or  last year (for monthly), I need to scan whole table of size more than 10,00,000 records, which is time consuming & nginx gives 502 error.

User & Outlet model doesn't have any association.

User contains the field outlet_code which is unique in outlet table

Comment: If you want to print 10.000.000 objects in a page I think you will need some kind of pagination or endless page (infinite scrolling). That could solve your perfomance problem in retrieving the objects. See [will paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate), I used this gem and worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Users registered in last 12 months:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today - 12.months)
```

Users registered in last 30 days:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today - 30.days)
```

Users registered in last day:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today - 24.hours)
```

Users registered this year:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today.year)
```

Users registered this month:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today.month)
```

Users registered today:

```
@users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today)
```

Example of how to render:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

<%= user.outlet_code %><br><br>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I executes this query @users = User.where('created_at >= ?', Date.today - 12.months) then it's taking too much time to execute because it returns more than 10,00,000 records for each month. If I used batch processing then it increases execution time & nginx gives response 502 bad gateway for ajax call. How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you need these records? If you are trying to use in any meaningful way, I would do this: `1.` Add infinite scroll or pagination. This will only return a small set of queries (25, 50, 100 etc.) `2.` Add either filters or attribute searching to work with the records. So for example, you can return 100 per page for 1000 pages (yikes). But then, you run a search for "Monica" and it reduces the count to 55 or something. Or you filter by `gmail` accounts etc. Using the pagination allows you to return the objects quickly. Filters/searching allow you to find what you need.